# Libgdx - create multiple balls

Tags: java, android, libgdx

So I have this simple pong game but I'm trying to change it up a bit, the thing is I'm currently struggling with having to duplicate or create various balls in the game for it to work the way I want to. I'm uncertain if I should use an arraylist and if so how should I do it? any suggestions would really be appreciated.

```
 public class ColorPong implements ApplicationListener {

private Rectangle field = new Rectangle();
private Ball ball = new Ball();
private float fieldTop, fieldBottom, fieldLeft, fieldRight; 





@Override
public void create() {
    field.set(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    fieldLeft = field.x;
    fieldRight = field.x + field.width;
    fieldBottom = field.y;
    fieldTop = field.y + field.height;
    ball.BallCreation();
    reset();


}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {

}

@Override
public void render() {
    float dt = Gdx.graphics.getRawDeltaTime();
    update(dt);
    draw(dt);

}

private void draw(float dt) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL30.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    ball.DrawingBall(dt);

}

private void update(float dt) {
    updateBall(dt);
}

private void updateBall(float dt) {
    ball.Intergrate(dt);
    ball.updateBounds();
    //------------------
    if(ball.Left() < fieldLeft){
        ball.move(fieldLeft, ball.getY());
        ball.Reflect(true, false);
    }

    if(ball.Right() > fieldRight){
        ball.move(fieldRight - ball.getWidth(), ball.getY());
        ball.Reflect(true, false);
    }

    if(ball.Bottom() < fieldBottom){
        ball.move(ball.getX(), fieldBottom);
        ball.Reflect(false, true);
    }

    if(ball.Top() > fieldTop){
        ball.move(ball.getX(), fieldTop - ball.getHeight());
        ball.Reflect(false, true);
    }

}

public void reset(){
    ball.move(field.x + (field.width - ball.getWidth()) / 2, (field.y + field.height) / 2);
    Vector2 velocity = ball.getVelocity();
    velocity.set(300, 150);
    velocity.setAngle(360f - 45f);
    ball.setVelocity(velocity);



}

@Override
public void pause() {

}

@Override
public void resume() {

}

@Override
public void dispose() {

}
```

}

and here is the Ball class

```
private ShapeRenderer ballRenderer;
private Color ballColor = new Color();


public Ball() {
    super(32, 32);

}

public void Reflect(boolean x, boolean y){
Vector2 velocity = getVelocity();
if(x) velocity.x *= -1;
if(y) velocity.y *= -1;
setVelocity(velocity);
}

public void BallCreation(){
    ballRenderer = new ShapeRenderer();
}

public void DrawingBall(float dt){
    ballRenderer.begin(ShapeType.Filled);
    drawBall(dt);
    ballColorSwap();
    ballRenderer.end();

}

int THRESHOLD = 900; // 4 seconds
long lastChanged = 0; // timestamp
public void ballColorSwap(){
    // maybe call it here?
    if(System.currentTimeMillis() - lastChanged < THRESHOLD)
        return;
    int rnd = (int)(Math.random() * 4);
    switch(rnd){
    case 0: ballColor.set(Color.GREEN);break;
    case 1: ballColor.set(Color.BLUE);break;
    case 2: ballColor.set(Color.RED);break;
    case 3: ballColor.set(Color.YELLOW);break;
    }
    lastChanged = System.currentTimeMillis();
}

private void drawBall(float dt) {
    ballRenderer.circle(this.getX(), this.getY(), 20);
    ballRenderer.setColor(ballColor);

}
```

}

Comment: Without going into exact details, anytime you want a new ball you would have to make a new instance of a ball in your main Pong class. You would need an ArrayList of balls in order to keep track of the balls in your Pong class. So when you create the new ball, push it into your array list. Then just loop through your array list every draw cycle to draw each ball.

Comment: I see, but would the other balls be able to move around and perform the same task like the original ball or would I have to keep creating an update for each ball?

Comment: Yes they would. Instead of just doing an updateBall() like you're doing now, you would have to loop through your list of balls and call updateBall on each of them. However the way you have it set up now it wont exactly work. You will just need to make an update() in your Ball class so that you can easily loop through each ball and call .update() on it. You'd do a similar thing in the render() method. So you need to move the updateBall() stuff into your Ball class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java, whenever I want to keep track of an arbitrary number of objects I typically use an ArrayList; they are quite handy once you learn how to use them effectively.

Here's an example of how you might use an ArrayList with your update and updateBall methods:

```
//initialize in create()
ArrayList<Ball> balls;


private void update(float dt) {
    //Pretty much saying 'For every ball in Balls, assign it to 'b' and do something with it
    for(Ball b : balls) {
        updateBall(b, dt);
    }
}
private void updateBall(Ball b, float dt) {
    b.Intergrate(dt);
    b.updateBounds();
    //------------------
    if(b.Left() < fieldLeft){
        b.move(fieldLeft, ball.getY());
        b.Reflect(true, false);
    }

    if(b.Right() > fieldRight){
        b.move(fieldRight - b.getWidth(), b.getY());
        b.Reflect(true, false);
    }

    if(b.Bottom() < fieldBottom){
        b.move(b.getX(), fieldBottom);
        b.Reflect(false, true);
    }

    if(b.Top() > fieldTop){
        b.move(b.getX(), fieldTop - b.getHeight());
        b.Reflect(false, true);
    }

}
```

And of course to draw the ball, just do the for(Ball.... thing again and call b.DrawingBall()

Comment: In this example how do you determine the amount of balls that should be duplicated?

Comment: Say in updateBall() you add a check to see if this ball should be duplicated, if so, create a new ball, set the position to the one to be duplicated, and add it to the ArrayList. 

ex:

`Ball newball = new Ball();`
`newball.setX(oldball.x);`
`newball.setY(oldball.y);`
`//Maybe give it a random direction`
`balls.add(newball);`